# How to achieve select tag overflow behavior in bootstrap dropdown

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-select, dropdown

I am using a Bootstarp dropdown in my HTML.
How can I achieve the same overflow behavior of the select HTML tag,
I added a code snippet.

I can't use the select because of complex styles (images and buttons) of the items.

I'm hosting the html in a Web Broser Control inside a winform application. Beneath the html there is other C# Control that hides the items if I use the select tag. I added this information just to explain my problem (The same behavior can be explained with Iframe tag).

> Note: make sure to minimize the window to achieve the overflow, if you
>   copy this HTML.

Click here to see the [desirable Select behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laikk.jpg).

Click here to see [comparison between the controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipBSi.jpg)

Thanks in advance

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">click me
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>AAA</li>
    <li>BBB</li>
    <li>CCC</li>
    <li>DDD</li>
    <li>EEE</li>
    <li>AAA</li>
    <li>BBB</li>
    <li>CCC</li>
    <li>DDD</li>
    <li>EEE</li>
   <li>AAA</li>
   <li>BBB</li>
   <li>CCC</li>
   <li>DDD</li>
   <li>EEE</li>
   <li>AAA</li>
   <li>BBB</li>
   <li>CCC</li>
   <li>DDD</li>
   <li>EEE</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <select style="position: fixed; left: 200px; top:0px;">
   <option>click me too</option>
   <option>BBB</option>
   <option>CCC</option>
   <option>DDD</option>
   <option>EEE</option>
   <option>AAA</option>
   <option>BBB</option>
   <option>CCC</option>
   <option>DDD</option>
   <option>EEE</option>
   <option>AAA</option>
   <option>BBB</option>
   <option>CCC</option>
   <option>DDD</option>
   <option>EEE</option>
   <option>AAA</option>
   <option>BBB</option>
   <option>CCC</option>
   <option>DDD</option>
   <option>EEE</option>
  </select>
  <div style="color:red; font-weight:bold;">If you copy this html, minimize the window size before testing behavior<div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this,

```
<select class="form-control" style="position: fixed; left: 200px; top:0px;">
```

Comment: I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: add `class=''form-control'` inside your select tag. It will add `dropdown` style and solve your problem.

Comment: I have to use the dropdown button because of other styling issues and you suggest to use the select tag.

Comment: After searching,  trying,  and testing I couldn't find any answer to my question. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: I'm not clear about what you really want. Why don't you use same way you implemented you first drop downlist to second one.